# How to make HTML table cells as dropdown button using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make Two columns of my HTML table to be like drop down button. i have tried but all the rows been converted into drop-down button.
I only want specific columns to be drop-down in my table the are `categorycode` and `categoryname`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $dropdown = $("#contextMenu");
  $(".actionButton").click(function() {
    //move dropdown menu
    $(this).after($dropdown);
    //update links
    $(this).dropdown();

  });
  var tableData = [{
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C001",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Beverages",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 18
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C002",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Shakes",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 80
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C003",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Juices",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 70
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C004",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Soups",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 55
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C005",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Cookies",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 46
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C006",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Buns",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 21
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C007",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Breads",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 40
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C008",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Rusks",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 52
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C009",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Biscuits",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 38
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C010",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Puff",
      "QUANTITY": "4.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 132
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C011",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Savouries",
      "QUANTITY": "0.1000",
      "AMOUNT": 29
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C012",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Cake",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 46
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C014",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "IceCream",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 70
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C019",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Curry",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 180
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C021",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Starter",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 165
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C022",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Roti",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 60
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C023",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Chawal",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 185
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C024",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Dessert",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 66
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C026",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Soup",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 100
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C027",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Salad",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 50
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C028",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Set Menu",
      "QUANTITY": "3.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 1290
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C029",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Pastry",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 80
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C030",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Packed Meals",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 25
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C031",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Packaging",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 5
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C034",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Bhath",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 68
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C036",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Snacks",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 10
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C037",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Breakfast",
      "QUANTITY": "5.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 119
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C038",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Evening Snacks",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 70
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C040",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Sandwich",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 75
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C042",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Burger",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 75
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C043",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Meals",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 220
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C044",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Curd",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 12
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C048",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Combo",
      "QUANTITY": "2.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 180
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C051",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Silver Thali",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 450
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C052",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Sweets",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 115
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C054",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Instant Mixes",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 66
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C055",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "RTE",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 228
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C057",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Spices",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 40
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C061",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Fast Food",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 15
    }
  ]

   function addTable(tableData) {
       var col = Object.keys(tableData[0]); // get all the keys from first
         
       var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length; // count all which
                    // are number
       var num = col.splice(0, countNum); // cut five elements from frist
       col = col.concat(num); // shift the first item to last
       // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
       var table = document.createElement("table");

       // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

       var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.


         for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
           var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
           th.innerHTML = col[i];
                
           tr.appendChild(th);
       }

       // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
       for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {

           tr = table.insertRow(-1);

           for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
               var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                var tabledata = tableData[i][col[j]];
         if(tabledata && !isNaN(tabledata)){
           tabledata = parseInt(tabledata).toLocaleString('en-in')
         }
         if( tableData[i]['CATEGORY CODE'] === tableData[i][col[j]]){
             a = document.createElement("a");
             tabCell.classList.add("dropdown");
              a.classList.add("btn");
          a.classList.add("btn-secondary");
          a.classList.add("actionButton");
          a.classList.add("btn")
          a.classList.add("btn-secondary");
          a.classList.add("dropdown-toggle");
          a.classList.add("dropdown-toggle-split");
             /*  a.classList.add("text-center"); */
             /*  a.setAttribute("data-place", outlet);
             a.setAttribute("data-plac", element); */
             a.setAttribute("data-toggle", "dropdown");
             a.innerHTML = tabledata;
             tabCell.appendChild(a);
         } else {
             span = document.createElement("span");
             span.innerHTML = tabledata;
             tabCell.appendChild(span)
         } 

            
         
         
         
         
         
         
         
 
                   if (j > 1)
                    {
                  
                   tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
                    }
           }
       }

       // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
       var divContainer = document.getElementById("table1");
       divContainer.innerHTML = "";
       divContainer.appendChild(table);
       table.classList.add("table");
        table.classList.add("table-striped");
        table.classList.add("table-bordered");
 
       }
  addTable(tableData)

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
 <script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 
 <script
  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="table1">
</div>
<ul id="contextMenu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li><a href="#" class="link1">BillSummary</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link2">Item Summary</a></li>
</ul>
```

Drop-down button is secussfully loading but i  don't know why drop-down is not populating. i have provide `ul` tag also but it not showing, i don't know where i a making mistake please any one out here help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var tableData = [{
                "CATEGORY CODE": "C001",
                "CATEGORY NAME": "Beverages",
                "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                "AMOUNT": 18
            },
            {
                "CATEGORY CODE": "C002",
                "CATEGORY NAME": "Shakes",
                "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                "AMOUNT": 80
            },
            {
                "CATEGORY CODE": "C003",
                "CATEGORY NAME": "Juices",
                "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                "AMOUNT": 70
            },
            {
                "CATEGORY CODE": "C004",
                "CATEGORY NAME": "Soups",
                "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                "AMOUNT": 55
            },
            {
                "CATEGORY CODE": "C005",
                "CATEGORY NAME": "Cookies",
                "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                "AMOUNT": 46
            },
            {
                "CATEGORY CODE": "C006",
                "CATEGORY NAME": "Buns",
                "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                "AMOUNT": 21
            },
            {
                "CATEGORY CODE": "C007",
                "CATEGORY NAME": "Breads",
                "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                "AMOUNT": 40
            },
            {
                "CATEGORY CODE": "C008",
                "CATEGORY NAME": "Rusks",
                "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                "AMOUNT": 52
            },
            {
                "CATEGORY CODE": "C009",
                "CATEGORY NAME": "Biscuits",
                "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                "AMOUNT": 38
            },
            {
                "CATEGORY CODE": "C010",
                "CATEGORY NAME": "Puff",
                "QUANTITY": "4.0000",
                "AMOUNT": 132
            }
        ]

        function addTable(tableData) {
            var col = Object.keys(tableData[0]); // get all the keys from first

            var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length; // count all which
            // are number
            var num = col.splice(0, countNum); // cut five elements from frist
            col = col.concat(num); // shift the first item to last
            // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
            var table = document.createElement("table");

            // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

            var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.


            for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
                var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
                th.innerHTML = col[i];

                tr.appendChild(th);
            }

            // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
            for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {

                tr = table.insertRow(-1);

                for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                    var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                    var tabledata = tableData[i][col[j]];
                    if (tabledata && !isNaN(tabledata)) {
                        tabledata = parseInt(tabledata).toLocaleString('en-in')
                    }
                    if (tableData[i]['CATEGORY NAME'] === tableData[i][col[j]] || tableData[i]['CATEGORY CODE'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
                        a = document.createElement("a");
                        tabCell.classList.add("dropdown");
                        a.classList.add("btn");
                        a.classList.add("btn-default");
                        a.classList.add("actionButton");
                        /*  a.classList.add("text-center"); */
                        /*  a.setAttribute("data-place", outlet);
                         a.setAttribute("data-plac", element); */
                        a.setAttribute("data-toggle", "dropdown");
                        a.setAttribute("id", i);
                        a.innerHTML = tabledata;
                        tabCell.appendChild(a);
                    } else {
                        span = document.createElement("span");
                        span.innerHTML = tabledata;
                        tabCell.appendChild(span)
                    }










                    if (j > 1)
                    {

                        tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
                    }
                }
            }

            // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
            var divContainer = document.getElementById("table1");
            divContainer.innerHTML = "";
            divContainer.appendChild(table);
            table.classList.add("table");
            table.classList.add("table-striped");
            table.classList.add("table-bordered");
            table.setAttribute("id", "myexample");
        }
        addTable(tableData)

        //$dropdown = $("#contextMenu");
        for (var i = 0; i < $('#myexample tr').length; i += 1) {
            var row = document.getElementById("myexample").rows[i];
            $("#" + i).click(function (e) {
                //console.log($(this));                
                   //console.log(e.target.innerHTML);                
                // Ajax Call while clicking on table
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'getdata.php',
                    data: {id: $(this).attr('id')},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log((data));
                        $("#" + data.id).after($(data.html));
                        $("#" + data.id).dropdown();
                    },
                    error: function (er) {
                        console.log(er);
                    }
                });
                // end code


            });
        }

    });
</script>


/*Please create PHP file(getdata.php) and put below code*/
/*You can use own logic to fetch dynamic data*/
/*
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['id'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    if ($id == '1') {
        $html = '<ul id="1" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="link1">BillSummary</a></li>
            <li><a href="# class="link2">Soups</a></li>
            <li><a href="# class="link3">Star</a></li>
        </ul>';
    } else if ($id == '2'){
        $html = '<ul id="1" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="link1">My C003</a></li>
            <li><a href="# class="link2">My Cookies</a></li>
            <li><a href="# class="link3">MyFavourite</a></li>
        </ul>';
    }
    echo json_encode(array('id'=>$id, 'html'=>$html));    
}
?>

*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<div id="table1">
</div>
<ul id="contextMenu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li><a href="#" class="link1">BillSummary</a></li>
  <li><a href="# class="link2">Item Summary</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please try above code. I have adding dynamic id while creating rows.
previously, click event not happen because all cell have same class and you not iterate loop toward which cell clicked. Based on dynamic ids it will fire event and dropdown will display.

Comment: hey i have tried your code but facing an issue while getting data via ajax

Comment: Let me know, issue in detail. I have run code and it's working which you shared detail to show in dropdown. Share detail so i will help you

Comment: yup its working fine but when i am using latest bootstrap and getting data with ajax call its showing error like  `TypeError: t is null; can't access its "setAttribute" property`

Comment: Dear dheeraj, Please do not provide your feedback by editing the answer, instead provide your inputs using the comments or editing your own question with the additional information. The answer edit feature is not for "collaborating". Your(OPs) code and your inputs go in the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Dipti hey can you help me out?

Comment: Please verify. I have updated code. Calling AJAX(getdata.php) while clicking on Category Code with parameter. Based on received response showing dropdown. This should work. Check for C002, C003 you can update based on dynamic id. (Copy commented code in php file and check). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: ( I didn't test, just came to my mind )

```
if(tableData[i]['CATEGORY NAME'] === tableData[i][col[j]] || tableData[i]['CATEGORY CODE'] === tableData[i][col[j]]){
    a = document.createElement("a");
    tabCell.classList.add("dropdown");
    a.classList.add("btn");
    a.classList.add("btn-default");
    a.classList.add("actionButton");
    /*  a.classList.add("text-center"); */
    /*  a.setAttribute("data-place", outlet);
    a.setAttribute("data-plac", element); */
    a.setAttribute("data-toggle", "dropdown");
    a.innerHTML = tabledata;
    tabCell.appendChild(a);
} else {
    span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerHTML = tabledata;
    tabCell.appendChild(span)
}
```